# Having an issue with cURL (PHP)

Tags: php, curl, https

So I have a licensing system that has an API with it, though I barely understand cURL. Could someone please explain what I did wrong?

Most of this code was pulled off of the documentation for the API I'm using.

Here is the code within my PHP login page.

```
function checkLicense() {
    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_URL => "https://www.scriptic.xyz/wp-json/lmfwc/v2/licenses/", $licensekey ,"?consumer_key=", $consumer_key ,"&consumer_secret=", $consumer_secret ,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
    CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
    CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => false,
    CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
    CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET",
    ));

    $response = curl_exec($curl);
    $err = curl_error($curl);

    curl_close($curl);

    if ($err) {
        return "cURL Error #: " . $err;
    } else {
        return $response;
    }
}
```

Error:

```
cURL Error #: Could not resolve proxy: ?consumer_key=
```

Edit: When I visit the link using a license key from the database in the spot "$licensekey" and filling in the other two variables it returns the json I want.

The URL it should look like to get the json:
https://www.scriptic.xyz/wp-json/lmfwc/v2/licenses/license-key-example?consumer_key=key-example&consumer_secret=secret-example

Here is the json it returns

```
{"success":true,"data":{"id":"5","orderId":null,"productId":null,"licenseKey":"hidden-for-privacy","expiresAt":null,"validFor":"0","source":"2","status":"3","timesActivated":null,"timesActivatedMax":"0","createdAt":"2019-11-07 01:43:16","createdBy":"1","updatedAt":null,"updatedBy":null}}
```

Edit 2:

I have changed `,` to `.`

```
$consumer_key = "hidden-for-privacy";
$consumer_secret = "hidden-for-privacy";
$licensekey = $_SESSION['key'];

function checkLicense() {
    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
        CURLOPT_URL => "https://www.scriptic.xyz/wp-json/lmfwc/v2/licenses/". $licensekey ."?consumer_key=". $consumer_key ."&consumer_secret=". $consumer_secret,
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
        CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
        CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
        CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
        CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => false,
        CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
        CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET",
    ));

    $response = curl_exec($curl);
    $err = curl_error($curl);

    curl_close($curl);

    if ($err) {
        return "cURL Error #:" . $err;
    } else {
        return $response;
    }
}
```

New Error:

```
{"code":"lmfwc_rest_authentication_error","message":"Consumer key or secret is missing.","data":{"status":401}}
```

Comment: Where do you set the variables `$licensekey`, `$consumer_key`, `$consumer_secret`?

Comment: What is `$ch`? Should those really be `,` or `.`?

Comment: I set the variables right above it
`
$consumer_key = "hidden-for-privacy";
$consumer_secret = "hidden-for-privacy";
$licensekey = $_SESSION['key'];
`

Comment: Now that you filled in the variables, you seem to be getting a valid response. What's the problem?

Comment: `$ch` should be `$curl`.

Comment: Ok, I'm getting a response from the API now, but now it's saying Consumer key or secret is missing, I did change it from `,` to `.`

Comment: Edit the question in the code to show the changes you've made, and the new error messages.

Comment: Can't see what your actual code now is so no idea.

Comment: hint: curl_setopt_array() on line 4 returns bool(false) which means there was an error in curl_setopt_array(), but you forgot to check the return value.

Comment: You still have a variable scope issue. Variables are only accessible to the function they defined in, called via global scope, or passed in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok the issue is solved thank you to everyone who helped. I moved the variables inside the function and now it's returning what I want.